# A dyslexic friend wants to play with an online group in a text-based game; how can I help them participate?

Tags: group-dynamics, accessibility, play-by-chat

I have a group of remote friends who often play RPGs by written message only - primarily playing live. I'm starting up a new game, and one of the players who's asked to join has moderate dyslexia, and has had problems in the past both typing longer messages and keeping up with reading a constant flow of messages.

I want them to be able to play in this game. However, in our case, voice chat is not an option for continuing play - it's not even a remote possibility; simply asking people if they can play by voice won't work. And, my dyslexic friend doesn't want to use a TTS system.

To my un-accessibility-trained eye, this has sort of exhausted the list of possibilities. Is there any way I can help them participate that I'm not seeing, or is this situation just not one in which this person can effectively participate?

Comment: First off -> thanks for taking this into consideration. Props for taking the effort to make your table as inclusive as possible. While, there's no single correct answer to this question, I'd recommend reading up on common resources for writing/designing content for a Dyslexic reader. There are many articles on how to create and tailor content for a dyslexic audience: A quick example: http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/writing-for-dyslexic-readers

Answer (score 15):

It all depends on what type of dyslexia your friend has. Using the [Dyslexie font](https://www.dyslexiefont.com/en/dyslexie-font/) may help with keeping up with the wall of text. It helps me when I'm writing, I don't get really bad headaches because I am straining to make out the words. Coloured lenses also help, may need to find a optometrist that has dyslexia training.

Comment: actually the colored lenses can be gotten over the counter, so no visit to a eye doctor is necessary

Comment: If the point of colored lenses is to change the color layout of the text, it's probably cheaper and easier to change your display settings; there's tools that can change the color distribution of your screen.